How would std::optional need to be modified in order to make it a monad via coroutines?
There's not really much when searching for c++coroutine "optional", but from the final part of this answer I'd deduce that std::optional can't be made to work with the coroutine below non-intrusively, i.e. without changing std::optional. However, I want to understand the details of this fact.
Here's the coroutine:
template<typename T>
std::optional<T> plus(std::optional<T> a, std::optional<T> b) {
  co_return (co_await a) + (co_await b);
}

By "work with the coroutine" I mean that this should pass:
assert(plus(std::make_optional(3), std::make_optional(4)) == std::make_optional(7));
assert(plus(std::make_optional(3), std::nullopt)          == std::nullopt);
assert(plus(std::nullopt,          std::make_optional(4)) == std::nullopt);

I guess I'm a bit confused by the fact that std::optional plays at the same time several roles

type return type of the coroutine, because it is... the return type of the coroutine
the awaitable, because it is operand to co_await
the container of the value that is passed to co_return (if neither co_await has suspended yet because its operand was std::nullopt)

and I'm not sure which of these roles, if any, implies that std::optional would need to be modified.
Especially 1 and 3 together are most confusing to me, because the coroutine should return the object via std_optional<T> promise_type::get_return_object(), but at that time the returned object is empty (or is it?), but then the co_return, if the code gets to that point, would need to alter that very object, but what would void promise_type::return_value(auto v) do to make that happen?
Below is some attempt to reason about the first part of the question (i.e. "does std::optional need to be modified?") and here is a failed attempt at implementing a std_optional alternative to std::optional.

In the coroutine body, both co_await expressions will/won't cause suspension depending on whether their argument is/isn't empty; whether it is empty is determined by the await_ready member function of the awaitable (and the value returned to the coroutine if the optional isn't empty would be available via await_resume of the same awaitable).
struct awaitable {
bool await_ready() const { return o.has_value(); }
auto await_resume() { return o.value(); }
//...
}

Now, despite the operands to co_await are std::optional, that per se doesn't mean std::optional need to be made an awaitable (which would be intrusive, as one would have to open std::optional and define the 3 await_* functions in it), but one can just define a co_await operator with a custom awaitable:
template<typename T>
auto operator co_await(std_optional<T> o) {
    struct awaitable {
        std_optional<T> o;
        bool await_ready() const { return o.has_value(); }
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<>) {}
        auto await_resume() { return o.value(); }
    };
    return awaitable{o};
}

As far as the two co_awaits expressions in plus are concerned, the promise type too can be provided in a way that is not intrusive to std::optional:
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
struct std::coroutine_traits<std_optional<T>, Args...> {
    struct promise_type {
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        std_optional<T> get_return_object() { return {}; }
        void unhandled_exception() { throw; }
        void return_value(auto) {}
        T val;
    };
};

Indeed, with this just in place, we can see that a call like this
auto o = plus(std::make_optional(3), std::make_optional(4))

will result in evaluating (co_await a) + (co_await b) to 7, which is correct, but what does not happen is that that 7 should be made available in the returned std::optional.
My understanding is that putting 7 in the std::optional returned to plus's caller is return_value's job.

(¹) On the other hand this proposal by Barry Revzin incidentally mentions the same thing (but for std::expected), saying that it can be made to work in a fully-conformant way, but I'm not sure if that's implying that no change to std::expected would be needed or what.

Are you trying to treat a std::optional like it was a std::future?

@Eljay, no. But your comment makes me think I could actually look at this example on cppreference that does something relatively similar with std::future.

namespace.std: "Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace std provided that (2.1) the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined type, and..." But std::coroutine_traits<std::optional<T>, Args...> does not depend on any program-defined types, so it is not allowed.

What do you mean by "made a coroutine"? What you seem to want is to (ab)use co_await to unpack an optional<T> into a T. That doesn't make optional into a "coroutine"; it merely becomes an awaitable type.

@NicolBolas, I obviously used the wrong terminology, sorry. Hopefully now it's better?

You have to wrap it as any type (your plus might return a (wrapped) int instead of a (wrapper) std::optional...

Note that the proposed co_await relies on the coroutine machinery to catch the bad_optional_access exception and (presumably) turn it into a nullopt_t. This is a very inefficient way of doing a null test.

There are two related pieces I believe:  First, std::optional needs to be awaitable, and second std::optional<T> foo() needs to be a coroutine.

I think void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<>) {} is sort of key; when optional isn't ready, you need to inject std::nullopt into the returned optional.

For a toy example, we'll start with a notstd::optional that allows someone to remotely provide it with state:
namespace notstd {

template<class T>
struct optional {
  std::shared_ptr<std::optional<T>> data;
  optional():data(std::make_shared<std::optional<T>>()) {}
  explicit optional(std::shared_ptr<std::optional<T>> p):data(p) {}

  template<class U> requires std::is_constructible_v<std::optional<T>>
  optional(U u):optional( std::make_shared<std::optional<T>>(std::forward<U>(u))) {}

  explicit operator bool() const { return data && *data; }
  bool has_value() const { return (bool)*this; }

  T const& value() const { return **this; }
  T value() && { return std::move(**this); }
  T& value() & { return **this; }

  optional(optional&&)=default;
  optional(optional const&)=default;
  optional& operator=(optional&&)& =default;
  optional& operator=(optional const&)& =default;

  T& operator*() { return **data; }
};

Next, our promise_type:
template<class T>
struct optional_promise_type {
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    notstd::optional<T> get_return_object() { return val; }
    void unhandled_exception() { throw; }
    void return_value(T t) {
      *val.data = std::move(t);
    }
    notstd::optional<T> val;
};
}

the magic is in return_value, where we end up populating the already-existing get_return_object's state.
The semantics of our notstd::optional don't match std::optional exactly, but fixing that should sound plausible to you (we just need to have a way to get a hook into the pre-existing object's state).
Everything else is sort of pedestrian?
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
struct std::coroutine_traits<notstd::optional<T>, Args...> {
  using promise_type = notstd::optional_promise_type<T>;
};


namespace notstd {
  template<typename T>
  auto operator co_await(optional<T> o) {
    struct awaitable {
        optional<T> o;
        bool await_ready() const { return o.has_value(); }
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<optional_promise_type<T>> h) {}
        auto await_resume() { return o.value(); }
    };
    return awaitable{o};
}
}

notstd::optional<int> add( notstd::optional<int> lhs, notstd::optional<int> rhs ) {
  co_return co_await lhs + co_await rhs;
}

I'm betting it probably leaks, but you can probably fix that in await_suspend.
int main() {
  auto x = add(3,4);
  auto y = add({}, 4);
  std::cout << (bool)x << (bool)y << "\n";
}

this prints 10 as you'd expect.
Live example.
The flow looks sort of like this.
We call add.  The return object is created, then the code starts to run.
When you hit co_await on a notstd::optional, if there is data we extract it immediately and continue.  If there isn't data, we suspend with no way to unsuspend.  There is probably a way to trigger cleanup here, I'm just not an expert, so I think we leak for now.  Maybe just a call to .destroy() on the coroutine handle would do it?
The return value of the promise_type starts off as a nullopt equivalent, so it is correct; once suspended, the calling code has what appears to be an empty optional.
If it doesn't suspend in any co_await, we end up with a co_return.  Our co_return expects a T (I could modify it to accept an optional<T>, to allow explicit nullopt return, but I don't want to).
When we hit it, we go off and populate the already returned optional<T> from get_return_object with the value.  Then we are done; the coroutine cleans up.
(Invoking destroy() seems correct: live example - but I don't know coroutine lifetime rules well enough to guarantee it.)

You say the magic is in return_value, but isn't even more magic in holding the payload on the heap via std::shared_ptr? (Incidentally, I think the std::optional inner layer is redundant, as std::shared_ptr can itself alone encode the optional-ness.) I mean, the std::shared_ptr is what allows the connection between the two separate objects: one is the by-value val member of optional_promise_type, and the other is its copy that gets returned from get_return_object. You dereference the .data of the former to alter the latter.

As in, it feels that such an implementation requires heap allocation of the payload of the [not]std::optional. Making val a reference would not help, as it would not be rebound anyway in get_return_object.

@Enlico Sure, but notstd::optional could carry around an optional self** which it updates with its own identity when it moves, allowing itself to be updated externally, without using a heap allocation.  The requirement of "some way" to updated it after it is created is the problem there.

I'm not sure I understand how that would help. The return value of get_return_object() and the val member of the promise are two dinstinct copies (as long as val is of value type and get_return_object returns by value, at least), so how can val alter something in its copy if neither of them is pointing to a common thing on the heap? Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "an optional self** ...".

@Enlico The optional has a pointer to a pointer to itself.  When it is moved, it updates that pointer to the pointer to itself to continue to point to itself.  In the promise object, you have the pointer to the returned optional.  This lets you modify it without a different allocation.  No heap involved.  struct tracked { tracked** ppself; tracked(tracked** pp):ppself(pp) { *ppself = this; } tracked(tracked&& o):ppself(o.ppself){*ppself=this;} int x;}; - construct tracked with a &pTracked and pTracked will point to the object even after it is moved.

@Enlico Regardless if you understand it, however, "you can do this without a heap allocation" is true.  You just need to be able to "remote update" the state of the returned optional through one hack or another.
